# Returning data in a HTTP Response outside the HTML?

Tags: html, http

Basically, I want the server to be able to send some data back to the client, except that this data will only become available after the entire HTML blob has already been generated. Specifically, I want to put a time-to-render (TTR) indicator on every page:

[image]

Currently the time is being measured from the point the first component starts rendering up to the point at which the last component is rendered. However, this misses out on the time needed by all the other stuff like middleware (I'm using Django) that goes on before/after the main HTML Blob is rendered.

If i measure it from the final post-post-processing point, I cannot just append the TTR string onto the HTML blob because the final /html tag has already been done. I could possibly do some clever regex-string-replace-thingy to insert it *inside* the blob, but that feels very dirty.

I could just *not* append the closing /body /html tags until this stuff is done, but that feels equally dirty: I'll have to purposely split off the "closing" tags of the main page from the rest of the page just so I can put the TTR indicator before those tags.

Is there anyway I could have a fully formed HTML page, and just tack on some tags *after* the final /body /html tags that would contain this information, that I could Javascript into my TTR div, while having it still be valid html? Or is there any way to pass back metadata along with the HTML blob, which my Javascript could read and also place into my TTR div? Or is there any other better way of doing this that I am completely missing out on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just put the container into your HTML as you generate it, and populate it with a string that you know won't appear anywhere else in the document. Then you can simply `str_replace()` it in 'post-post-processing'.

You could, if your feeling brave, try and do something similar with `sprintf()` but I suspect that would occasionally result in odd output because of the fact that the conversion specifications for sprintf are so simple, and you may end up with them intentionally appearing somewhere in the document. Also (on my PHP 5.2.17/Win32 at least) `sprintf()` is slower than `str_replace()` for a single replace term.

If you are generating you page as a string and not sending any output to the browser until the very end, or you are output buffering, you *could* set a cookie that is accessible from Javascript and have the browser do a `document.getElementById('an_element').innerHTML = cookieValue;` onload, but I would say that relying on Javascript for this would give you another layer of things to get muddled up along the way/generally go wrong.

If you can't set headers by the time you have finished rendering the HTML because you have already sent some content, you would have the same problem as with statically placing the data on the page - you can add a `<script>` after `</body></html>` either...

Comment: Hmmm, I did not think of using Cookies. They seem (at first sight) as exactly what I was looking for, except I would not use them persistently but send a new one down with each page. Is there any downside to using them? Having them as a dictionary of key/value strings seems the perfect way of separating this data from the main HTML blob, and I can later Javascript them onto the page in the right place. This would solve a bunch of my other problems too; there are a few other post-HTML-generation variables that I want to pass to the javascript

Comment: The key disadvantage of cookies is that the user can disable them. Aside from that, they are a fairly reliable and well standardised - it's one of those rare things where the same JS should work in every browser. There should be no problem with sending a new cookie value with each request - that is how most cookie-auth routines work. To give yourself room to easily correct browsers stupidity, set the cookies to expire at the end of the session (pass `0` to the `$expire` parameter of `set_cookie()`) so the user can just close the browser and re-open to clear them.

Comment: Scratch the `set_cookie()` reference, forgot we were dealing with Python... And all the other PHP references in the answer, lol!

Comment: Does disabling cookies mean they are never received in the first place, or just that they are not stored? The way you said it sounds like the former, but Google doesn't confirm/deny anything; it seems most people use cookies for inter-page persistence and not intra-page communications.

Comment: Like you say, cookies or more used for storing state between pages, rather than for passing data to the client, but there's nothing that says you can't. Cookies will always be *recieved* (unless they are stripped out the response by a proxy along the way - *very* unlikely) but the user can choose to trash them and not store/use the data they contained. To be honest, I have stopped writing for people who have set their browsers up in this way - no-one has ever come up with an argument that convinces me it gives you any real security benefit, or any other good reason for doing it.

Comment: Let's put it this way - the people who have disabled cookies have probably also disabled Javascript, so it blows the whole idea out of the water for them anyway. If your site relies on javascript for things other than this, the user is not going to get a decent user-experience anyway.